# I just clicked "answering help" when editing a question, and it seems the page had buttons that aren't required

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

I clicked the *answering help* on the *edit answer* page.

[image: How to Format]

Which lead me to here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

[image: Answering help]

The buttons down the bottom of the document make it appear that this page is an intermediate to answering questions (my guess for low rep users).

But in *this* context, the buttons are meaningless and somewhat confusing.

If following the path *I* took, could we have the buttons removed?

Comment: I think you are the first person to voluntarily click that kink.  Kudos.

Comment: @jjnguy I'm curious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.